# xming - How to build Xming from sources?

Tags: windows, xorg, compile, build, xming

I'm trying to build Xming from its sources available on [SourceForge](https://sf.net/p/xming).
I know this version is outdated and have considered just buying it, but for my use case **building it is required**. I know that [VcXsrv](https://sf.net/p/vcxsrv) has better build instructions, but I have a few *problems* with its license (GPLv3). Because [Xming](https://sf.net/p/xming) doesn't have any instructions except the [official X.Org instructions](https://www.x.org/wiki/Building_the_X_Window_System/), which are of no use on Windows, I was wondering if anyone here might know how to build it? I've tried using the [official X.Org instructions](https://www.x.org/wiki/Building_the_X_Window_System/), but no luck (weird gmake errors I wouldn't like to debug).

> Note: The [X.Org instructions](https://www.x.org/wiki/Building_the_X_Window_System/) I linked are too new, I actually tried using the instructions provided in the `BUILD` file available after extracting the [`.tar.bz2 file`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/Xming-source/6.9.0.31/Xming_69031_source.tar.bz2/download)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.